# How to remove newline CRLF in PowerShell?

Tags: powershell

I wrote script, but i don't understand, how to remove newline?

```
Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem name | select name -ExpandProperty Name | Out-File C:\Distrib\test.txt 
    $a=Get-Content C:\Distrib\test.txt
    $b=$a.split('-')
    $c=$b[$b.Length-1]
    $c = $c | foreach {"S"+$_} 
    $c | Out-File C:\Distrib\test.txt
```

Comment: Hows does the file looks like now and how do you want it to look like?

Comment: You can try TrimEnd(). I remember using it in the past.
[see documentation](https://ss64.com/ps/trim.html)

Comment: [`Get-Content`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/microsoft.powershell.management/get-content?view=powershell-6) doesn't produce any content with newlines but an **array** of lines.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See [Get-Help Out-File](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/Microsoft.PowerShell.Utility/Out-File?view=powershell-5.0) and guess what the parameter `-NoNewline` is for?

You could shorten your script to

```
'S'+(Get-WmiObject win32_computersystem).Name.Split('-')[-1] |
    Out-File C:\Distrib\test.txt -NoNewline -Enc default
```

Without -Encoding you'll get Unicode with a BOM